# Unable to build QtMock in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, linker-errors

Just downloaded https://qt.gitorious.org/~niandong/qt/niandongs-qttools/commits/qtmock since I'm in desperate need of mocking a QNetworkAccessManager.

I was able to build the qtmock.pro in QtCreator 2.3.1 using Qt 4.7.4. All the tests ran as they should and I got very exited!

Then I had to build it with visual studio to be able to use the libraries of my project and all of its dependencies. I'm using Qt 4.8 here in Visual Studio 2010 pro. I imported the main qtmock.pro and first I tried to build the underlying qtmock project that only contains the framework (no tests or anything). It built fine and I got a .lib and .dll file. Then I tried to build the qtnetworkstub.pro where all the mock objects for QNetwork are which I need for my project. The following is my command line for the build:

> /OUT:"......\lib\qtnetworkmock.dll" /NOLOGO
>   /LIBPATH:"E:\QT\4.8.0\lib" /LIBPATH:"e:\QT\4.8.0\lib"
>   /LIBPATH:"../../../lib" /DLL "../../../lib\qtmock.lib"
>   "E:\QT\4.8.0\lib\QtTestd4.lib" "E:\QT\4.8.0\lib\QtCored4.lib"
>   "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib"
>   "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib"
>   "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST
>   /ManifestFile:"Win32\qtnetworkmock.dll.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /DEBUG /PDB:"E:.Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\lib\qtnetworkmock.pdb"
>   /PGD:"E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\lib\qtnetworkmock.pgd" /TLBID:1
>   /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

and I'm only using the testLib and the Core.

I then got the following linkin error:

```
Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) referenced in function "public: __thiscall QNetworkRequest::~QNetworkRequest(void)" (??1QNetworkRequest@@QAE@XZ) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkrequest.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 5 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QTcpSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QTcpSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkreply.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 6 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QTcpSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QTcpSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkrequest.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 7 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QSslSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QSslSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkreply.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 8 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QSslSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QSslSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkrequest.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkaccessmanager.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkproxy.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 3 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject const QAbstractSocket::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@QAbstractSocket@@2UQMetaObject@@B) E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\test\stublib\network\qnetworkreply.obj qtnetworkstub
Error 9 error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals E:\src\Qt.UnitTest\qtmock\lib\\qtnetworkmock.dll qtnetworkstub
```

The thing that I dont get is: I'm not using any of these objects and they arent refered anywhere in that project. All of them inherits from QIODevice but I'm not too sure how much that will help.

I'm extremy stuck and I would appreciate any help since I really want to use this framework (it seems really great for unit testing!)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is an issue with QTMock and Qt 4.8 and has nothing to do with visual studio. The current available build of QtMock does not work with 4.8 (only 4.7 and possibly lower) but will be fixed very soon.